# Why split ELL and ELU?

Tags: discussion, english-language-and-usage

Why create ELL when a huge percentage of ELU questions that I have seen appear to be from non native English speakers and are asking for things that few native speakers need.  Is there a consensus from ELU mods that two SE sites are needed?

Comment: Yes, and look how many of those ELU questions about super-basic English-learner stuff get downvoted, closed, and deleted. Most of them.

Comment: There's a very good answer to this [there](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3723/24489) by a user active on both sites.

Comment: ELL was created for precisely the reason you indicate: a huge percentage of ELU questions were from non-native English speakers asking for things that few native speakers need. Those questions seemed largely out-of-place for that venue, but the community wanted a place where those questions would be welcomed, rather than downvoted for being too basic. They are legitimate questions, when presented to the right audience.

Comment: @StoneyB -- thanks for the pointer.  I would follow ELU if I had time, but I don't; but after I retire, ...  In the meantime, I hope I can provide some help on ELL.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ELU is for etymologists, linguists, and serious English language enthusiasts, while ELL is for people who are learning English. I don't see it as splitting ELU into two sites. Instead, I see it as creating a new site for a different audience. Although the two sites cover much of the same material, they cover different aspects of it, and are thus distinct.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the sites is the target audience: *English Language Learners* is for people learning English. As such, I would not expect questions about Old English on ELL, or questions asking a deep analysis about the etymology of a word.

Probably, there are questions that are on EL&U that would have been asked on ELL, if both the sites were created at the same time, but that doesn't mean the sites are two different purposes and audiences.